# Wrong Eigenvector after Hotelling deflation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm using the [Power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) combined with the [Hotelling deflation](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~sjrob/Teaching/EngComp/ecl4.pdf) to find all Eigenvalues and the corresponding Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices.

When testing my implementation, I found out that a resulting Eigenvector $v_b$ of the deflated matrix $B$ is not an Eigenvector of the original matrix $A$, however $v_b$ is an Eigenvector of $B$. The Eigenvalues are computed correctly. It would be great if somebody could check what I'm doing wrong within the Hotelling deflation.

Following computations were performed with Octave. The original matrix is this 3x3 matrix
$$
        A = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1& 2  & 1\\
        3 & 2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
with the three Eigenvalues and corresponding Eigenvectors
$$
        \lambda_{A1} = 5.236 \quad  v_{A1}=[-0.648, -0.400, -0.648]^T \\
        \lambda_{A2} = -2.000 \quad  v_{A2}=[-0.707, 0.000, 0.707]^T \\
        \lambda_{A3} = 0.764 \quad  v_{A3}=[0.465, -0.400, -0.753]^T.
$$

Then I'm removing the most significant Eigenvector $v_{A1}$ from the matrix $A$ by applying the Hotelling deflation, as
$$
        B = A - \lambda_{A1} \cdot v_{A1} \cdot {v_{A1}}^T = 
      \begin{bmatrix}
        -1.198 & 0.6414 & 0.802 \\
        -0.358& 1.160  & -0.358\\
        0.802 & 0.641 & -1.198 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The Eigen-pairs of $B$ are 
$$
        \lambda_{B1} = -2.000 \quad  v_{B1}=[0.707, 0.000, -0.707]^T \\
        \lambda_{B2} = 0.000 \quad  v_{B2}=[0.648, 0.400, 0.648]^T \\
        \lambda_{B3} = 0.764 \quad  v_{B3}=[0.436, 0.788, 0.436]^T.
$$
As expected, one of the Eigenvalues is zero. $\lambda_{B1}$ and $v_{B1}$ are an Eigen-pair of both $B$ and the original matrix $A$. $\lambda_{B3}$ and $v_{B3}$, however, are only an Eigen-pair of the matrix $B$. It fails badly with the matrix $A$
$$
    A \cdot v_{B3} \neq \lambda_{B3} \cdot v_{B3}\\
    \begin{bmatrix}
        3.318 \\
        2.446\\
        3.318 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \neq 
\begin{bmatrix}
        0.332 \\
        0.601\\
        0.332 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm aware that there exist better deflation methods, such as the Wielandt deflation. It was also mentioned that the Hotelling deflation suffers from rounding errors. But for me this looks not like a rounding issue. Would be great if somebody could give me a hint.

Comment: $A$ is not symmetric...

Comment: The methods you're using work only (in their most simple version) on symmetric matrices.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I took this as an example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient_iteration#Example Ok, that explains why it worked with some other examples. Thanks a lot!